# How do you bind to a TimeSpan field when you want the user to enter total seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, timespan

I have a TimeSpan property that can be edited in a TextBox.  The TextBox uses a converter to convert from string to TimeSpan and back again.  The problem is that the user must enter a formatted string like hh:mm:ss, and so on.  I want the user to only be able to enter a whole number representing the total number of seconds.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It was right in front of me...just had a typo.  Converter must simply do this:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((TimeSpan)value).TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    /// <see cref="IValueConverter.ConvertBack"/>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse((string) value, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
```